# Angular {{ func(variable) }} is called multiple times

Tags: angular

If in the views one calls a function on the variable such as:

```
{{ myFunc(test) }}
```

This function is executed multiple times rather than 1.

I have it defined my function as:

```
  myFunc(s: string) {
    console.log("I am being called")
    return s;
  }
```

and looking at the console log one can see that function is being executed 4 times. Created [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jprqgs) to illustrate.

In my project where function is called from a service I get ~20 console.logs.

Seems very inefficient, why is this happening?

Comment: It's not at all recommended using function in Angular2+ to bind data, use a variable instead.

Comment: This is expected behavior. You should avoid calling functions in expressions. Whatever you are trying to do, there is another way. Further reading: http://spraso.com/functions-in-angular-expressions-are-killing-your-performance/

Comment: your template gets rendered every time angular assumes you have a change in the state. Every time it renders the template it should recalculate the data it needs to display, so your function is getting called. It is very much logical and correct

Comment: This is a great article related to what you are asking. [When not to use methods in HTML Templates in Angular](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16)

Comment: Thanks, this investigation helped me to understand some important points!

Comment: @Wagm - Even I learn by answering questions. I also had no idea about this :)